# Is there anyway to make 'disable middleclick on iframe only' work correctly in firefox?

Tags: javascript, browser

```js
$('#mchatframe').on('mousedown', function(e) {
  if (e.which === 2) {
    return false;
  }
});
```

```css
#mchatdiv {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid rgb(5, 180, 1);
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100%;
}

#mchatframe {
  scrolling: no;
  transform: scale(1.052);
  border: 0px none;
  margin-top: -80px;
  margin-bottom: -125px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mchatdiv">
  <iframe scrolling="no" id="mchatframe" src="/forum/app.php/mchat">
 </iframe>
</div>
```

Works great in chrome and IE. Firefox however it is very random. Half the time it semi-works; it disables middle-click entirely (instead of just in the iframe), the other half of the time it does nothing at all.

Is this just a firefox limitation or is there a known fix?

No headway made on this issue. No code seems to affect firefox properly in terms of disabling middle-click on a specific div or iframe.

Comment: Have you tried handling `click` instead of `mousedown`?

Comment: Makes no difference.